# How can I use JSON Where Clauses on laravel mongodb? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, json, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3

My data on mongodb compass is like this :

[image]

I read from here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#json-where-clauses

I try to implement json where clauses like this :

```
Message::where('information->seller_id', 1)
       ->get();
```

The results are not showing. Whereas the data exist

This query seems still wrong

I try read reference here : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

But, I don't find it

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why downvote? There is something wrong?

Comment: I think column data type should be json. In your case `information` column should be data type of json.

Answer (score 1):

To select data from inside JSON, use a `.` instead of `->`

```
Message::where('information.seller_id', 1)
       ->get();
```

Also, your data is currently a `string`, and you need it to be `JSON`. Just remove the quotes around it:

`information : {"store_id":6,"some_other_data":"123", "seller_id":1}`

Comment: That is worked for laravel (5.8.36) mongodb (4.0.14)